# Expression for getting text between 1 or 2 sets of parens? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following:

```
POLYGON((7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531,3.1060409545898438 24.7247314453125,8.64349365234375 22.052650451660156,14.989128112792969 26.966629028320312,7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531))
```

I can also have the following:

```
POLYGON(7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531,3.1060409545898438 24.7247314453125,8.64349365234375 22.052650451660156,14.989128112792969 26.966629028320312,7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531)
```

Noting the difference in parens. I only always wants the data inside the innermost set of parents so I can split on the commas.

I had something like this       `let coordFinder = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;` but it's not getting me both cases.

Comment: You need to add `(` into the character class. `\(([^()]+)\)`

Answer (score -1):

You could do one of the following:

```
\([^()]*\)
```

Or, getting down to the digits and dots and commas,

```
\([.,0-9 ]*\)
```

**UPDATE**: added snippet (works as expected) => matches both versions with one or two sets of parameters

```js
var poly2 = "POLYGON((7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531,3.1060409545898438 24.7247314453125,8.64349365234375 22.052650451660156,14.989128112792969 26.966629028320312,7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531))",
poly1 = "POLYGON(7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531,3.1060409545898438 24.7247314453125,8.64349365234375 22.052650451660156,14.989128112792969 26.966629028320312,7.593955993652344 33.70124816894531)";

console.log(poly1.match(/\([.,0-9 ]*\)/));
console.log(poly2.match(/\([.,0-9 ]*\)/));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let coordFinder = /.*\((.*?)\)/;

var test1 = '((abc(123,456)))';

var test2 = '(abc)';

console.log('result in test1: ' + test1.match(coordFinder)[1]);

console.log('result in test2: ' + test2.match(coordFinder)[1]);
```